# How can I find a $2 x 2$ matrix $A$ that satisfy the following properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

a) $A^2 \neq I_2$, $A^4 = I_2$

b) $A^2 =A$ all entries of $A$ are nonzero.

By the way, a and b are different questions. They are different matrices that I need to find.

Comment: Please use appropriate formatting. Otherwise it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Think of what $A$ must represent in terms of linear transformations.

$(a)$ Can you think of a transformation that is not the identity if you apply it twice, but that leaves things unchanged if you apply it four times? **Hint:** try rotations!

$(b)$ Can you think of a kind of transformation that leaves things unchanged if it's already been applied? **Hint:** try projections!

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 1: the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $i$ and $-i$

Hint for 2: if $v$ is a norm $1$ vector, then $vv^T$ is a projection matrix